Issue with Outlook custom properties in shared calendar appointments
I am using VBA to add an appointment to a shared calendar that includes a custom property, here's an example of the code:
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objNamespace As Object
Dim objCalendar As Object
Dim objAppointment As Object
Dim vPropPath  As String

Set objOutlook = GetOutlookApp()
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objCalendar = GetOutlookCalendar()

Set objAppointment = objCalendar.items.Add(1)

objAppointment.Subject = vTitle
objAppointment.Body = vBody

vPropPath = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/7771001F"
objAppointment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty vPropPath, "1"

objAppointment.Save
objAppointment.Close 0 

Set objAppointment = Nothing
Set objCalendar = Nothing
Set objNamespace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

When I check the custom property of the created appointment, it is present initially. However, after Outlook syncs with the Exchange server or when the appointment is edited, the custom property is removed.
Thanks in advance.

Keep in mind that Outlook recreates appointments (thus wiping out all custom properties) when it receives appointment updates/notifications from the organizer. Is that the case?

Yes, that is the case. Is there any way to preserve custom properties in this scenario?

Not really, not on the appointment itself. The only thing that is guaranteed to stay the same is the AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID property. Entry id changes since that will be a brand new item. You can store the mapping GlobalAppointmentID vs your property externally, either in a file of a hidden (associated) message,.

You are correct. However, this solution has two challenges:
First, There is a delay in assigning the GlobalAppointmentID from the Exchange server, so it cannot be retrieved immediately after creation. A scheduled process is required to get it later using the EntryID.
Second, If the user clones the appointment in Outlook, there is no reliable way to map the cloned item.

For the second point, unless the associated hidden message is also cloned along with the appointment (I will check this part).

Hidden message can be used to store the map for all appointments in the folder, not just a particular appointment.

Got it, Thank you very much for your help.
